# React native create custom modal using render props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-props

I want to create a Modal component and I want to have possibility to inject to it everything what I want. Firstly I decided to use HOC but then I've changed my solution to render props. Everything works fine but I don't really like this solution. I'm wondering how could I optimize it to make it better. What is the best practise to create such kind of modal where you have button opening this modal beyond modal component. I really don't like that now I have two components with open/close state of modal. And both of them have a toggle method to open/close modal. Any suggestion? Maybe I should stick with the HOC ?

Here's the code with Component.js where CustomModal is used:

```
toggleModalVisibility = (visible) => {
    this.setState({modalVisible: visible});
};

render() {
    const question = this.props.questions[this.props.counter];
    return (
            <View style={styles.questionContainer}>

                <CustomModal
                    visible={this.state.modalVisible}
                    toggleModalVisibility={this.toggleModalVisibility}
                    render={() => (
                        <>
                            <Text>{question.text}</Text>
                            <Text>{question.details}</Text>
                        </>
                    )}
                />
                <View style={styles.questionTextContainer}>
                    <Text style={styles.questionText}>{question.text}</Text>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.toggleModalVisibility(!this.state.modalVisible) }>
                        <FontAwesome5 name='question-circle' size={30} color='#B7DBF3' light />  
                    </TouchableOpacity>                          
                </View>
            </View>
    )
}
```

and here's the code of CustomModal.js

```
export default class CustomModal extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        isOpen: this.props.visible
    };
}

componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (prevProps.visible !== this.props.visible) {
        this.setState({isOpen: this.props.visible});
    }        
}

toggle = (isOpen) => {
    this.setState({ isOpen });
    this.props.toggleModalVisibility(isOpen)
}

render() {
    return (
        <View>
            <Modal
                animationType='slide'
                transparent={false}
                visible={this.state.isOpen}
            >
                <View style={{marginTop: 30, marginLeft: 5}}>            
                    <TouchableHighlight
                        onPress={() => {
                            this.toggle(!this.state.isOpen)
                        }}>
                        <FontAwesome5 name='times-circle' size={30} light />  
                    </TouchableHighlight>
                    <View>{this.props.render()}</View>                      
                </View>
            </Modal>
        </View>
    )
}
```

}

Comment: I would use `redux`. Have a `client` reducer that you can track a modal state. Then you can display the modal via an action, the payload of that action could be the content to render

Comment: You could create a `ModalButton` component, which would be a button that opens it's own `Modal`, and if you need specific information from the `Modal`, you could have an `onChange` prop for a callback function. `ModalButton` can take care of the visibility state of the `Modal` instead of its parent component.